# Jquery script that parses HTML into JSON array not appending in correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

Hi guys here i use this script below to grab an `html table` from another page and turn it into a `json array` and then i append it into my newsfeed with parameters but for some reason the order of things gets messed up for 2-3 of the items which makes no sense... I want to fix that and also tell my script to only append last 10 items how can i accomplish this?

the JS:

```
$.get( "http://support.jonar.com/support/default.asp?W2423", function(data) {
  var frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(data);
  var tbl = (frag.querySelector('.newsfeedtable'));
  document.body.appendChild(tbl);
  var data = $(tbl).tableToJSON();
  tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);


  data.reverse().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.priority < b.priority || Array.prototype.slice(-5);
  }).forEach(function(d, i) {
    var title = d.title;
    var link = d.link;
    var date = d.date;
    var type = d.type;
    var location = d.location;
    var priority = d.priority;
    if (priority == '1') {
        $('ul.nflist').prepend($('<li>', {
            html: '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a> ' + ' ' + '<span class="category">' + type + '</span>'
        }));
    } else if (location === 'customer_and_partner_portal') {
        $('ul.nflist').append($('<li>', {
            html: '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a> ' + ' ' + '<span class="category">' + type + '</span>'
        }));
    }
    else if (location === 'customer_portal') {
        $('ul.nflist').append($('<li>', {
            html: '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a> ' + ' ' + '<span class="category">' + type + '</span>'
        }));
    }
  });

  //First hide the category tag...
  $(".category").hide();
  // Now lets search for categories and add images
    $('ul.nflist li:contains("social_media")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/customer/img/icons/socialmedia.png" />');
    $('ul.nflist li:contains("blog")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/customer/img/icons/blogicon.png" />');
    $('ul.nflist li:contains("announcement")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/customer/img/icons/announcementnews.png" />');
    $('ul.nflist li:contains("press")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/customer/img/icons/inthepress.png" />');
    $('ul.nflist li:contains("paragon")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/customer/img/icons/ParagonUpdate.png" />');
    $('ul.nflist li:contains("event")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/customer/img/icons/events.png" />');
    $('ul.nflist li:contains("partner")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/customer/img/icons/partnerupdate.png" />');
    $('ul.nflist li:contains("wiki")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/customer/img/icons/wikiUpdate.png" />');
        // Now if there is an alert please make it red!
    $('ul.nflist li:contains("alert")').addClass("ALERT").prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/customer/img/icons/ALERT.png" />');
});
```

The script works great i just want to append last 10 items in the `json array`.. I know its `array.prototype,slice(-10)` but not sure how to apply it.

Here is what the table looks like :

http://jsfiddle.net/sxk0k8kh/

As you can see the order there is an order to the document but here in the image below you see that it does not follow... The second to last item in the table is in the wrong place and it happens with two others. Here below is an image of the output.

[image: the output of my script]

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on and what you want to accomplish

Comment: Its simple the order of the appended items are incorrect... My js is clean i dont know what is going on. Look at the output image and the html table you will see that the order in which they appear is incorrect @Adjit

Comment: I don't know the order that they are supposed to be in

Comment: If you look at the fiddle the table is all in a row correct? and if you look at my js `data.reverse()` all i did was reverse the order.. Which is fine if you look at the `html table` and the output image you will see that the second item is not correct.. @Adjit

Comment: You sort the array by priority, but final order of elements with same priority is undefined.

Comment: i really don't understand my code then.. I assumed i told it to 1. `if priority 1 add it first` `if it has this field then add it to the html` `if it has this field then add it to the html` this is what i thought i did.. @OrestHera how can i fix this?

Comment: Yes, but before you have `sort(function(a, b){}`.

Comment: so how can i reverse the `json array` order  but just add the priority 1's at the top? @OrestHera

Comment: Try without `sort()`: `data.reverse().forEach()`. Note that you always prepend elements with priority `1`. So, if there are more than one such element they will be reversed again.

Comment: @OrestHera WORKED! please put it as answer so i can mark you as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data items are sorted by priority using `.sort()`. After soring the final order of elements with same priority is undefined.

Since you have only two options for priorities: `0` and `1`, you can remove `sort()`:

```
data.reverse().forEach(function(d, i) {
    //...
  });
```

However, if there are more than one element with priority `1` they will be reversed again.

It can be done smarter. It is possible to assign order index for all elements:

```
data.forEach(function(d, i) {
    // store inside elements their initial order
    d.idx = i;
})
```

Now that array can be sorted by priorities, but for equal priorities we can check initial order index:

```
// sort taking into accound initial order
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (parseInt(a.priority) == parseInt(b.priority))
        return b.idx - a.idx; // reverse order of elements with same priority

    // move elements with higher priority on top
    return parseInt(b.priority) - parseInt(a.priority);
});
```

The compare function should return negative, zero or positive values if element `a` is respectively lower, equal or higher `b`. So, string values for priorities should be converted to integers.

It is not needed to call `.reverse()`, since order index is already taken into account during sorting. Do your main for each loop using only `.append()`, since elements with higher priorities are first:

```
data.forEach(function(d, i) {
    //...
    //    $('ul.nflist').append(...);
})
```

Comment: can you add all these items into the JS script that i posted abit confused :)

Comment: euhm.. for some reason it didnt work properly.. it added the priority on top but the reverse order does not work!

Comment: @RajaSharma I was misled by your initial compare function. Now it is fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/orest_h/hkqp0dzr/3/ So, there are added ordering indexes, fixed sort function and your initial loop with `append` instead of `prepend`.